# Safe number of parallel Wikipedia requests

Tags: web-crawler, wikipedia

What is a safe number of parallel GET requests I can make to Wikipedia without them limiting me, or getting mad at me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because either this is documented by wikipedia themselves or you will have to go and ask them, specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They state some [API:Etiquette](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Etiquette) and [API:FAQ](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:FAQ).

> There is no hard and fast limit on read requests, but we ask that you
>   be considerate and try not to take a site down. Most sysadmins reserve
>   the right to unceremoniously block you if you do endanger the
>   stability of their site.
>
> If you make your requests in series rather than in parallel (i.e. wait
>   for the one request to finish before sending a new request, such that
>   you're never making more than one request at the same time), then you
>   should definitely be fine. Also try to combine things into one request where you can (e.g. use multiple titles in a titles parameter instead of making a new request for each title

API FAQ states you can retrieve 50 pages per API request.

You can use [Data Dumps](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps) as well if you need content offline (likely a little outdated).

For a graceful termination of your script in case you hit any of the limits, you can handle errors & warnings in API calls using [these](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Errors_and_warnings) status messages.